# Bluemix - Assigning Space Quota while creating space

Tags: ibm-cloud

I am trying to create a space with a specific space quota plan assigned through CF CLI command. I had created a space quota plan called myPlanTiny and fired the CLI command as below.

*cf create-space mySpace1 -o my_org1 -q myPlanTiny*

The space got created, however the quota plan assignment did not take effect. Only the default plan got assigned to the newly created space.  My Bluemix account is a public bluemix account.

Requesting your help to understand why the space quota assignment does not take effect.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assigned quota is set to default for each newly created space, both from UI and CF CLI. This quota is related to the org and not to the single space in public Bluemix. Anyway there is a reserved set of cf commands that only administrators can run. These commands include for example things around quota and creating orgs, this could be the reason why you are not able to change the quota. If you are an Admin you should be able to set a custom quota and use it in a newly created space using the command you provided. After doing this, if the command `cf space <spacename>` still shows the default I suggest you to open a support request using one of the following methods in order to engage the Bluemix Project Office Team:

- Use the Support Widget. It is available from the user avatar in the 
     upper right corner of the main Bluemix UI.  After opening the support 
     widget panel, select Get Help > Get In Touch , select the type of 
     assistance you need, and then fill out the support form.
- Use the Support Site 'Get Help' form. This form is available on a separate site that is made available for ticket submission when you cannot log into Bluemix and access the Support Widget.  Go to http://ibm.biz/bluemixsupport and fill in the support request form.

Answer (score 1):

**1)** update your CF CLI 
**2)** create quota: cf create-space-quota myQuota -i 256M -m 256M -r 5 -s 5 --allow-paid-service-plans 
**3)** create space and assign your quota: cf create-space personalSpace -q myQuota 
**4)** if the issue is still there open a new ticket.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your help.

I updated the CF CLI version to 6.16.1+924508c-2016-02-26 and created a space quota and a space set to the newly created quota.

I verified the space-quota set on the space using the command below

cf space SPACE_NAME

It showed up the correct details.

Initially, I got confused with by the tiles on the dashboard was saying 1 GB/16 GB Used.  I guess that is shown at the org level and probably a functionality as designed.

The issue is resolved .  Thanks!!!

Comment: Yes it is the Org quota. I'm glad that it works, thank you!